# Jetpack compose application freezes on start up

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, coroutine

I have an android application built by jetpack-compose. When my MainActivity starts, it calls some composables. But the problem is that after showing the first composable, it freezes and I cannot interact with it for a few seconds (about 30 seconds).
What could be the problem?

Here is my HomeViewModel (It is the main page corresponding view model.):

```
...
init {
    val labels = context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.main_page_home_sortings)
    for (index in 0 until labels.size * 2) {
        _assetModels.add(MutableStateFlow(PagingData.empty()))
    }
    viewModelScope.launch(handler) {
        getAssetListUseCase.saveAssetListInDatabase()
        retry()
    }

}

fun retry() {
    var params = arrayListOf(
        Pair(SortedBy.PRICE, SortingType.ASC),
        Pair(SortedBy.PRICE, SortingType.DSC),
        Pair(SortedBy.VOLUME, SortingType.ASC),
        Pair(SortedBy.VOLUME, SortingType.DSC),
        Pair(SortedBy.GAINERS, SortingType.ASC),
        Pair(SortedBy.GAINERS, SortingType.DSC),
        Pair(SortedBy.MARKET_CAP, SortingType.ASC),
        Pair(SortedBy.MARKET_CAP, SortingType.DSC),
    )
    for (param in params) {
        val index = params.indexOf(param)
        getAssetModels(param.first, param.second, _assetModels[index])
    }
}

fun getAssetModels(
    sortedBy: SortedBy, sortingType: com.example.ramzinium.data.SortingType,
    state: MutableStateFlow<PagingData<AssetModel>>,
) =
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        jwt?.let { UseCaseInput(it, sortedBy, sortingType) }?.let {
            getAssetListUseCase.execute(it).distinctUntilChanged()
                .cachedIn(viewModelScope).collect() {
                    state.value = it
                    _dataLoadedFromNetwork.update { true }
                }
        }

    }
```

Main Activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mainActivityViewModel = ViewModelProvider(
            this, MainActivityViewModelFactory(navigationImpl)
        )[MainActivityViewModel::class.java]

        authenticationViewModel = ViewModelProvider(
            this, AuthenticationViewModelFactory(
                navigationImpl, GetUserUseCase(
                    AuthenticationRepositoryImpl(
                        ApiRequest.getInstance()
                    ), context = baseContext
                ),
                AuthorizationForgotPasswordUseCase(AuthenticationRepositoryImpl(ApiRequest.getInstance())),
                baseContext
            ) {
                homeViewModel.onUserAuthenticated(it)
            }
        )[AuthenticationViewModel::class.java]
setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
NavigationEffects(
                navigationChannel = mainActivityViewModel.navigationChannel,
                navHostController = navController
            )
            val paddingValues = WindowInsets.systemBars.asPaddingValues()
            ExtendedTheme {
                val originDirection = LocalLayoutDirection.current
                CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides originDirection) {

                    Scaffold(Modifier.padding(paddingValues)) {

                        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalRippleTheme provides NoRippleTheme) {

                            NavHost(
                                navController = navController,
                                startDestination = Destination.MainScreen.fullRoute,
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(it)
                            ) {
...
}}...}
```

HomeMainComposable:

```
fun HomeMainComposable(
    homeViewModel: HomeViewModel,
    newsViewModel: NewsViewModel,
    onNavigate: OnNavigate? = null
) {
    val pagerPages by remember {
        mutableStateOf(listOf("home", "market", "news", "converter"))
    }
    val icons = listOf(
        painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_main_page_home),
        painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_main_page_market),
        painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_main_page_news),
        painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_main_page_converter)
    )
    val navigationDrawerState = homeViewModel.navigationDrawerState.collectAsState()
    val updateTime = homeViewModel.updateTime.collectAsState()
 var selectedItem by remember {
        mutableIntStateOf(0)
    }

    var showLoginBottomSheetState = homeViewModel.showLoginBottomSheet.collectAsState()
    var showNewsFilterBottomSheetState = newsViewModel.showNewsFilter.collectAsState()

    var showChangeIntervalBottomSheetState by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val context = LocalContext.current
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        homeViewModel.showLoginBottomSheet(context)
    }
ModalNavigationDrawer(drawerState = navigationDrawerState.value.drawerState, drawerContent = { ... }){
//The resut is just compose code...
}

}
```

## Edit 2

I just realized that when I comment out the method `retry`, the app won't freeze, even though it is running on IO thread.

Comment: did u check the logs ANR ??? can u provide

Comment: Try calling `getAssetModels` from `Dispatchers.IO` thread instead of `Main` thread.

Comment: `viewModelScope.launch{ withContent(Dispatchers.IO) { ... } }`

Comment: Do you mean check for ANR in logcat? I have and nothing is there.

Comment: @MeghLath Do you mean `withContext`? I tried it and the problem is still there...

Comment: Please edit your post and also include the MainActivity code and the Composable that calls the ViewModel.

Comment: I just realized that the network call and database call causes this freeze. Though I have called them in coroutines. I'll edit the question and provide more info.